# Como mantener filas juntas en ITETXPDF 5

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Estoy armando un PDF para una lista de cuotas y funciona de la siguiente manera, si la cantidad de cuotas es igual a 36, esas cuotas  se muestren en la primera hoja más una descripción de totales debajo de la fila 36.Pero si es 37 a más, esas filas deberían ir en la siguiente hoja más la descripción de totales.Pero si abarcan mas de dos o más hojas la descripción de totales nunca debe quedar sola en una hoja.

LO que hice fue leer la lista y utilizar un contador internamente para que cuando sea igual a 36 **setKeepTogether(true)**, y vaya todo en una hoja. Pero la segunda parte aún no he podido desarrollarlo.
¿Alguna sugerencia para lograr esto?. Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido.Rahmen..., te saludamos y te damos la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**,  te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, agregar lo que has realizado, más información, etc, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Ver el ejemplo del sitio web iText:

```
/**
 * Este ejemplo fue escrito por Bruno Lowagie en respuesta a las siguientes preguntas:
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503491/large-table-in-table-cell-invoke-page-break
 */
package sandbox.tables;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import sandbox.WrapToTest;

@WrapToTest
public class NestedTables2 {
    public static final String DEST = "results/tables/nested_tables2.pdf";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        File file = new File(DEST);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        new NestedTables2().createPdf(DEST);
    }

    public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
        document.open();
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
        table.setSplitLate(false);
        table.setWidths(new int[]{1, 15});
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
            table.addCell(String.valueOf(i));
            table.addCell("¡No es inteligente usar iText 2.1.7!");
        }
        PdfPTable innertable = new PdfPTable(2);
        innertable.setWidths(new int[]{1, 15});
        for (int i = 0; i < 90; i++) {
            innertable.addCell(String.valueOf(i + 1));
            innertable.addCell("¡Actualiza si eres un desarrollador profesional!");
        }
        table.addCell("21");
        table.addCell(innertable);
        for (int i = 22; i <= 40; i++) {
            table.addCell(String.valueOf(i));
            table.addCell("¡No es inteligente usar iText 2.1.7!");
        }
        document.add(table);
        document.close();
    }
}
```

Esto está creando tablas anidadas, ya que `setKeepTogether(True)` no funciona en las celdas, sino en la tabla. Cuando llegue a 36, ​​puede crear la tabla externa.